# Add compiler flags to the standard android build.xml

Tags: android, ant

I want to add -Xlint:deprecated to the java compiler while building android app.
I've seen the compilerarg tag inside javac tags, but the generated build.xml for the standard project doesn't have such a tag.
Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

the full build script is located YOUR_SDK_FOLDER/platforms/SDKVERSION/templates/android_rules.xml

you modify your build.xml with copy of this file and customize it. Not sure if it'll get where you want - but it's a start

```
<!-- Execute the Android Setup task that will setup some properties specific to the target,
             and import the rules files.
             To customize the rules, copy/paste them below the task, and disable import by setting
             the import attribute to false:
                <setup import="false" />

             This will ensure that the properties are setup correctly but that your customized
             targets are used.
        -->
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `java.compilerargs` property in the default `$SDKDIR/tools/ant/build.xml` file that you can override in the `ant.properties` in your project, such as:

```
java.compilerargs=-Xlint:unchecked -Xlint:deprecation
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `<project>/app/build.gradle` (not the global build.gradle):

```
preBuild {
    doFirst {
        JavaCompile jc = android.applicationVariants.find { it.name == 'debug' }.javaCompile
        jc.options.compilerArgs = ["-Xlint:deprecation"]
    }
}
```